# RStudio Error: Unexpected Symbol (That Can't Be Found)

Tags: r, rstudio

Hoping someone with a sharper eye can help me out. When I run the two blocks of code below, the first chunk goes fine:

```
add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "exitLongNormal",
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = "all",
                          ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "long",
                          replace = FALSE,
                          prefer = "Open",
         type = "exit", path.dep = TRUE, label = "normalExitLong")

add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "exitLongFilter",
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = "all",
                          ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "long",
                          replace = FALSE,
                          prefer = "Open",
        type = "exit", path.dep = TRUE, label = "filterExitLong")
```

When ran the initial block gives me this:

```
> add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
+          arguments = list(sigcol = "exitLongNormal",
+                           sigval = TRUE,
+                           orderqty = "all",
+                           ordertype = "market",
+                           orderside = "long",
+                           replace = FALSE,
+                           prefer = "Open",
+          type = "exit", path.dep = TRUE, label = "normalExitLong")
```

Block two however, is the problem child, when ran I get the following:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"         type = "exit", path.dep = TRUE, label = "normalExitLong")
add.rule"
```

It seems like this would be something pretty simple to find, but for the life of me I just can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: The number of closing parenthesis you have do not match the closing. You have two opening for every one closing.

Comment: Where do I need extra parenthesis? I don't see it.

Comment: Seriosuly? open: `"add.rule("`; open: `"arguments = list("`; close: `"label = "filterExitLong")"`. repeat. I have no idea where all those named parameters belong so i'm not sure where your arguments list ends

Comment: Yes, seriously. This isn't my code. I tried watching a YT video and typing out all 200 lines to share with everyone who wants to try it out, but I can't figure out why this last "rule" isn't working, compared to the first.

Comment: you could atleast give us what package this code comes from...looks like some finance / trading strategy set up...but basically you've got two open parens and one closing parens...so you either need an additional closing parens at the end of `label = "normalExitLong")` or somewhere before that...but we have no way to know without knowing what function this comes from. Basically go look at the function parameters / definition / help page and you should be able to sort this out.

Comment: @Chase - Looks to be `quantstrat` going by this google result: https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/quantstrat/demo/luxor.5.strategy.ordersets.R?view=markup&revision=1499&root=blotter

Answer (score 3):

Here's the mismatched parens:

```
add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",                          # OPEN
         arguments = list(sigcol = "exitLongNormal",                # OPEN
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = "all",
                          ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "long",
                          replace = FALSE,
                          prefer = "Open",
         type = "exit", path.dep = TRUE, label = "normalExitLong")  # CLOSE
```